# python2 to python3 upgrade broke popen

Tags: python

I am an IT teacher in high school,
and asking my students to submit some homeworks written in C++.
As I am lazy, I wrote some python scripts to run and evaluate automatically their homeworks, and after I do just some ad-hoc manual checking if the automatic grade seems odd.
In python2 it worked ok, however in python3 I can't make it work.
Tried to encode() and encode('utf-8') the input,
I tried with communicate, tried to concatenate all the input and pass it then,
tried without the shell = True,
but the C++ program does not receive the numbers somehow...
Any ideas how can I make it work?

`````
def tester_1(filename):
    if 'system' in open(filename).read():
        return 2
    p = Popen(["g++",  filename], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    checkerror = p.communicate()
    grade = 4
    if (not 'error' in checkerror[1]):
        grade = grade +1
        #first test case
        if True:    
            p = Popen(['./a.out'], shell = True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
            p.stdin.write(str(3)+'\n')
            p.stdin.write(str(5)+'\n')
            p.stdin.write(str(7)+'\n')
            p.stdin.write(str(18)+'\n')
        
            result = p.stdout.readlines()
            if ( ("6" in result[-1]) and ("odd" in result[-1])):
                grade = grade +1
            if ( ("18" in result[-2]) and ("even" in result[-2])):
                grade = grade +1
            #close the C++ program
            p.terminate()
        #except:
        #    pass
        try:
            #second test case
            p = Popen(['./a.out'], shell = True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
        
            p.stdin.write(str(2)+'\n')

            p.stdin.write(str(6)+'\n')

            p.stdin.write(str(7)+'\n')
            results = p.stdout.readlines()
            result = results
            #get rid of spaces  
            #result[-1] = re.sub('[^0-9]','', result[-1])
            #result[-2] = re.sub('[^0-9]','', result[-2])
            if (("7" in result[-1]) and ("odd" in result[-1])):
                grade = grade + 1
            if (("6" in result[-2]) and ("even" in result[-2])):
                grade = grade + 1
            #close the C++ program
            p.terminate()
        except:
            pass
        try:
            #third test case
            p = Popen(['./a.out'], shell = True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
        
            p.stdin.write(str(6)+'\n')

            p.stdin.write(str(2)+'\n')

            p.stdin.write(str(2)+'\n')
            p.stdin.write(str(4)+'\n')
            p.stdin.write(str(3)+'\n')
            p.stdin.write(str(5)+'\n')
            p.stdin.write(str(3)+'\n')
            results = p.stdout.readlines()
            result = results
            #get rid of spaces  
            #result[-1] = re.sub('[^0-9]','', result[-1])
            #result[-2] = re.sub('[^0-9]','', result[-2])
            
            if (("2.66" in result[-2]) and ("even" in result[-2])):
                grade = grade +1
            if (("3.66" in result[-1]) and ("odd" in result[-1])):
                grade = grade +1

            #close the C++ program
            p.terminate()
        except:
            pass
        if (grade > 10):
            grade = 10
    return grade````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting the output and input to a file solved it.
the code looks like this, if anyone runs into something like this:

```
open("input.txt", "w").close()
with open("input.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(str(6)+'\n')
    ...        
input_file = open("./input.txt", "r")
output_file = open("output.txt", "w")

p = Popen(['./a.out'], shell = True, stdout=output_file, stdin=input_file)
p.wait()
output_file.close()
input_file.close()
result = open("output.txt", "r").readlines()
```